# F# pattern filtering

Tags: f#

Can someone please give me advice on how to filter out a list of lists when it contains a certain number. For example, if the sub-lists contain 2 then I want the third value.

```
let p = [ [0;2;1]; [7;2;5]; [8;2; 10]; [44; 33; 9]]
//Filtered List: [1;5;10]
let q = p |> List.filter(fun((x,y):int List)  (List.item 2 x) = 1,  (List.item 3 y))
```

Above is my code so far. I know its wrong but can't seem to figure it out in code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can just go by the way you described the problem:

```
p 
|> List.filter (List.contains 2) //first filter out lists with 2 in it
|> List.map (fun x -> x.[2]) //get the third element, this is the same as List.item 2 

//val it : int list = [1; 5; 10]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. that really helps.

Answer (score 6):

[s952163's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49124030/f-pattern-filtering/49124120#49124120) answer is correct, however, [List.choose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.choose%5B%27t,%27u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) would be better.

```
p
|> List.choose (fun list ->
  if List.contains 2 list then
    Some list.[2]
  else
    None
)
```

With the solution above you only iterate through the list once.